# Why does Mail Merge not available on Outlook 2010?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, mail-merge

As you can see from the attached picture "Mail Merge" feature is not available on my Outlook 2010? Could you please explain how can I use it? Also I added it from File>Options>Customize Ribbon>Choose Commands From->All Commands>Mail Merge. It was not stationed on Ribbon by default.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY9NW.jpg)

Comment: Which Windows version? Try: In *Control Panel > Programs and Features*, right-click Office and choose Repair, then reboot.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks. I did it but it is still unavailable.

Comment: Can you do the Mail Merge from Word? I think that Outlook 2010 had some difficulties with it.

Comment: @harrymc yes, Mail Merge is available at Word 2010. I forgot to mention, OS is Win 7. Do you have any other ideas about the problem? Microsoft Office's version is Professional Plus 2010.

Comment: Only two ideas: Upgrade Office, or do the Mail Merge from Word. But I don't know if you'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: @harrymc thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Mail Merge is not available Outlook 2010 but is available in Word 2010.

I can see only two options:

- Do the Mail Merge from Word,
- Upgrade Office to a later version.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u931i8dSeZw in this link it seems like they can use mail merge features. My problem is that I don't have any of these. There is only mail merge button and it is greyed out.

Comment: Is Outlook set to be your default email program?

Comment: Yes, there is no other email client on my computer, so it's the default.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Thw353M as you can see unfortunately I don't have it and don't know why?

Comment: See if [this post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/mail-merge-in-microsoft-word-does-not-work-on-a-computer-that-is-running-windows-7-or-windows-server-2008-r2-af89d1b8-fe9b-f8a2-90a5-c98474cefb44) lets you download the hotfix. If it does, install it, boot, start Outlook, exit, boot again. If still no go, do a repair of Office.

Comment: thanks, I found that article too. Also found the hotfix on some other site and tried to install but didn't happen.

Comment: I have run out of ideas. It's possible that in your version of Office (2010 had several) Outlook does not support Mail Merge. All you can do is ensure that Windows and Office are fully patched. If it still doesn't work, then only my above answer is left.

Comment: thanks a lot, now I'm downloading Service Pack 2 for Office 2010 and giving it a try. I'll share the results.

Comment: I've downloaded the SP2 for Office 2010 but nothing has changed.